# Convert string to timestamp in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following string representation of a timestamp in my Hive table:

```
20130502081559999
```

I need to convert it to a string like so:

```
2013-05-02 08:15:59
```

I have tried following ({code} >>> {result}):

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20130502081559999', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')) >>> 2013-05-03 00:54:59
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20130502081559999', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssMS')) >>> 2013-09-02 08:15:59
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20130502081559999', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssMS')) >>> 2013-05-02 08:10:39
```

Converting to a timestamp and then unixtime seems weird, what is the proper way to do this?

**EDIT**
I figured it out.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr('20130502081559999',1,14), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')) >>> 2013-05-02 08:15:59
```

or

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20130502081559999', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')) >>> 2013-05-02 08:15:59
```

Still... Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "better way" but you can always [write your own function](http://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/02/08/writing-hive-udfs-and-serdes/) to handle the date conversion.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like your format has three millisecond digits. I'd guess that, according to the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you would need to use the following:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20130502081559999', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your code does seems to drop the nanoseconds, is there a way to preserve it

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have input file like this

file:///data/csv/temptable/temp.csv

```
1   2015-01-01  
2   2015-10-10 12:00:00.232
3   2016-02-02
4   2015-09-12 23:08:07.124
```

Then you can also try this approach:

```
create external table temptable(id string, datetime string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile LOCATION 'file:///data/csv/temptable';

create table mytime as select id, from_utc_timestamp(date_format(datetime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'UTC') as datetime from temptable;
```

Comment: IMHO the best answer here

Answer (score 0):

If available you can simply use the following syntax

1) check whether what UDFs are available in your hive install?

```
show functions;
```

2) if seen from_unixtime() function then:

```
from_unixtime(your_timestamp_field)
```

This will solve the problem!

Please add comments, if you like my answer!