# Changing format of date field in Hive

Tags: date, hive

I have a Hive table that has the timestamps in this format 08/29/2015 0:00:08.  I have tried to use the unixtimestamp functions in order to isolate the date so I can use it for comparisons, but am always getting nulls for outputs.  I think I need to change the format to 2015-08-09 0:00:08 but don't know how.  I am new to Hive so any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: You can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796071/convert-string-to-timestamp-in-hive and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189790/date-format-conversion-in-hive

Comment: Have you tried the following format string: `unix_timestamp('08/29/2015 0:00:08', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a UDF to convert them to timestamps
`unix_timestamp("08/29/2015 0:00:08", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss")`

Check for help here :http://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-functions#date-functions