# how to group a date in a string type in hive

Tags: sql, types, group-by, hive

I have a date column, the data type is string as below,

my query is : 
select cast(substr(date,1,10),date) date , count(date) from table group by 
date;

```
date

1   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
2   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
3   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
4   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
5   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
6   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
7   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
8   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
9   1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
10  1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
```

so when I use group by date, there are still multiple rows for same day, I think I might need to convert the datatype into date, but still not working, anyone can help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to timestamp in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796071/convert-string-to-timestamp-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date and the column is a sting, just use `substr()`:

```
select substr(date, 10), count(*)
from t
group by substr(date, 10);
```

Ooops.  I realize your date is not a reasonable format (MM/DD/YYYY, say).  You can use `instring()`:

```
select substr(date, 1, instring(date, ' ')) as dte, count(*)
from t
group by dte;
```

Comment: so if I group by date, there are still multiple same dates in the result, what I expected is one date for each day only, no duplication

Comment: @JingHong . . . If your date is in the format you say it is, then the second version (with the fix) should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Date format in Hive is `yyyy-MM-dd`

if you want to **cast the string** field to **date** then use

```
hive> select date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date`, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) `date`,count(*) from dd group by date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date`, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'),'yyyy-MM-dd'));
+-------------+------+--+
|    date     | _c1  |
+-------------+------+--+
| 1970-01-01  | 10   |
+-------------+------+--+
```

In this statement we have did casting to date field to **date datatype** and grouped all the dates.

**(or)**

if you just want to group by on `MM/dd/yyyy` then use **split** function and group by

```
hive> select split(`date`,' ')[0] `date`,count(*) from dd group by split(`date`,' ')[0]; 
+-----------+------+--+
|   date    | _c1  |
+-----------+------+--+
| 1/1/1970  | 10   |
+-----------+------+--+
```